# Connecting to lxc container via SSH using lxc user

Tags: ssh, lxc

I noticed that the username/password I use to connect to a newly created LXC container via `lxc-console` doesn't work with ssh (with sshd running in the container). When I try, I get `Permission denied` Why is that, and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

inside container, open /etc/ssh/sshd_config and change PermitRootLogin to yes.

```
# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
```

Comment: In my case (ProxMox) I also had to 
apk add openssh to install openssh and then rc-update add sshd to autostart it

Answer (score 3):

A newly created LXC container using the ubuntu-cloud template comes with the SSH daemon configured to not allow passwords:

To fix this, attach to your container and edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file. Look for the following:

```
# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no
```

And change PasswordAuthentication to "yes" and restart SSH:

```
service ssh restart
```

Then you should be able to log in to your container with a password.

Answer (score 2):

Do you allow passwords for SSH? Do you have an iptables rule for port forwarding from your host to the LXC container IP address? You can add one with the following line (change port to your container's ssh port):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to 10.x.x.x:1234
```